# Getting blank space in tabbed activity fragment launch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout

[image]

This is my first fragment that is getting launched in the first tab. This fragment has a button clicking which I am supposed to launch this fragment with a new fragment. But while I do so the new fragment gets launched but there is a space on the top.
See the below picture:

[image]

In fact, the entire replaced fragment got slid down and went out of the screen below.
Those who are assuming that I have added a marginTop or paddingTop, to inform I have not added anything like that. In fact, if I replace the new fragment with some other fragment also the black space is still there on top. So it's not about the fragment with which I am replacing it.
Please help.

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.moodoff.AllTabs">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFC300"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
            android:background="#C70039"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

first_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/allmoods"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context="com.moodoff.Moods">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/firstRowOfMoods"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        >
<!--- SOME BUTTONS --->
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: write your code here and please check whether you didn't give any pedding in xml frame or fragment

Comment: please show your code. specially xml files.

Comment: main_activity that hosted three tabs given and the initial fragment for the first tab xml is given. replacing doesn't matter as any fragment instance i am using i am still getting the blank on top.

Comment: added xmls for reference